# JavaScript === operator returning false for same strings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two strings from different sources with `===` operator, they are seemingly identical, but I'm getting `false` as a result of comparison. This is the exact code I am running:

```
var a = 'House is green'; // got this value from source 1
var b = 'House is green'; // got this value from source 2
console.log(a === b); // false
```

**NOTE**

You won't be able to replicate the problem by copying code from the above because HTML seems to transform every variant of white space to `%20`.
That's why I created a simple stackblitz that replicates the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5aumq

Comment: You haven't explained _why_ they are different. Are they from different sources?

Comment: Your two strings are different. They have different white-space characters. If you copy one string into the other, it will return true.

Comment: @Andy Yes, they are from different sources. I just made the simple example here because I would need to write code for 5 different files in order to explain how I got them.

Comment: @Teemoh Yes, I realize that now. Also posted a solution below. Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though these two strings seem identical, I found out the hard way that they are not. If we use `encodeURI` to encode both of them to their UTF-8 representation, we will get the following result:

```
var a = 'House is green';
var b = 'House is green';
console.log(a === b); // false

console.log(encodeURI(a)); // House%20is%20green
console.log(encodeURI(b)); // House%C2%A0is%C2%A0green
```

First string actually uses regular white spaces (encodes to `%20`) and second one uses non-breaking white spaces (encodes to `%C2%A0`). The best solution that I managed to figure out so far is to use `replace` to find all space characters and replace it with regular white space character:

```
var c = a.replace(/\s/g, " ");
var d = b.replace(/\s/g, " ");

console.log(c === d); // true
```

Here's stackblitz that reproduces the problem and provides the solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmu8cg